# Call native php function in my PHP Extension

Tags: php, c++

Well, I started to learning about php extensions and I trying to call a native php function in my own function. The problem is that I have no idea how to do this.

```
ZEND_FUNCTION(new_decode){
char *arg = NULL;
char *decoded = NULL;
int arg_len, argc = ZEND_NUM_ARGS();
if (zend_parse_parameters(argc TSRMLS_CC, "s/", &arg, &arg_len) == FAILURE)
    return;
/*
    Is possible do this:
    decoded = base64_decode(arg);
    ???
*/
RETURN_STRING(decoded, true);}
```

Someone can tell me if I can do this?